# How to count duplicated messages of Idempotent Consumer with a metric?

Tags: apache-camel, metrics, micrometer

I have an Apache Camel application with an [Idempotent Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html). I need a metric with the total number of duplicated messages. How could I implement such a metric?

**Code**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory micrometerRoutePolicyFactory() {
    return new MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public EndpointRouteBuilder route() {
    return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
          from(file("d:/tmp/camel/"))
             .idempotentConsumer(jsonpath("$.id"), MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository())
             .to(file("d:/tmp/copy/"));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Research**

I looked into [`MicrometerConstants`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.15.x/components/camel-micrometer/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/micrometer/MicrometerConstants.java), but I couldn't find a metric for duplicate messages.

**Question**

How can I count the number of duplicate messages for Idempotent Consumer with a metric?

Comment: How can you tell that you have a duplicate message?

Comment: @checketts I can't tell, it is a feature of the Idempotent Consumer.

Comment: So you aren't asking how to record a metric, but rather how to find that info from Camel s you can expose it as a metric?

Comment: @checketts I can't find any built-in metric, so I'm looking for a custom way to expose such a metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, see 
[Idempotent Consumer](https://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/idempotent-consumer.html):

> **How to handle duplicate messages in the route**
> **Available as of Camel 2.8**
>
> You can now set the `skipDuplicate` option to `false` which instructs the idempotent consumer to route duplicate messages as well. However the duplicate message has been marked as duplicate by having a property on the Exchange set to true. We can leverage this fact by using a Content Based Router or Message Filter to detect this and handle duplicate messages.
>
> For example in the following example we use the Message Filter to send the message to a duplicate endpoint, and then stop continue routing that message.
>
> **Filter duplicate messages**
>
> ```java
> from("direct:start")
>     // instruct idempotent consumer to not skip duplicates as we will filter then our self
>     .idempotentConsumer(header("messageId")).messageIdRepository(repo).skipDuplicate(false)
>     .filter(property(Exchange.DUPLICATE_MESSAGE).isEqualTo(true))
>         // filter out duplicate messages by sending them to someplace else and then stop
>         .to("mock:duplicate")
>         .stop()
>     .end()
>     // and here we process only new messages (no duplicates)
>     .to("mock:result");
> ```

and [`MicrometerBuilders#micrometer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-endpointdsl/3.11.6/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/MicrometerEndpointBuilderFactory.MicrometerBuilders.html#micrometer-java.lang.String-):

> `default MicrometerEndpointBuilderFactory.MicrometerEndpointBuilder micrometer(String path)`
>
> Micrometer (camel-micrometer) Collect various metrics directly from Camel routes using the Micrometer library. Category: monitoring Since: 2.22 Maven coordinates: org.apache.camel:camel-micrometer Syntax: `micrometer:metricsType:metricsName` Path parameter: metricsType (required) Type of metrics There are 6 enums and the value can be one of: COUNTER, GAUGE, LONG_TASK_TIMER, TIMER, DISTRIBUTION_SUMMARY, OTHER Path parameter: metricsName (required) Name of metrics Path parameter: tags Tags of metrics
>
> **Parameters:**
> `path - metricsType:metricsName`
>
> **Returns:**
> the dsl builder

My modified code:

```java
@Bean
public EndpointRouteBuilder route() {
  return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       from(file("d:/tmp/camel/"))
         .idempotentConsumer(jsonpath("$.id"), MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository())
           .skipDuplicate(false)
         .filter(header(Exchange.DUPLICATE_MESSAGE).isEqualTo(true))
           .to(micrometer("duplicate_messages").increment("1"))
           .stop()
         .end()
         .to(file("d:/tmp/copy/"));
    }
  };
}
```